# How to use a text list to generate svg files?

Tags: svg, inkscape

I made a svg in inkscape. It's a Hiragana text.
Is there a way to batch export svg files from a list of Hiragana text?
That can be 46 Hiragana svg files.

`id="tspan849">あ</tspan></text>`

Comment: So, each SVG file is a result of your SVG file that you made in Inkscape with one of your texts? Should this work in a browser or created as files in the file system?

Comment: I need these svg files as game asset.    I realize svg is a graphic file format based on XML text, and wondered if I could batch modify the text and export them to files.  After a few days of experiment,  I finally accomplish it with Python.  Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I have write a py script to accomplish the task
Wish this py script can help people who need it.

```
#Check if the output folder is missing,it will create a new one, if output folder is not found.
import os
path = 'output'
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
#Create a List.
ListFileName='HiraganaList.txt'
with open(ListFileName, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    #Read the contents of the file into a list.
    lines=f.readlines()   
#Read the sample file.
SampleFileName='Hiragana_01.svg'
with open(SampleFileName, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as s:
    #Read the sample file contents into a list.
    sLines=s.readlines()
    #Output directory and named variables.
    OutFileFolder='Output'
    OutPixFileName='Hiragana_'
#Specifies the string to find.
sTokenString='あ'
iNum=1
#Cycle through List from first line to end line.
for line in lines:
    #Declares an output list.
    OutputContext=[]
    #Numbering
    sNum='0' + str(iNum)
    #Output file name + path
    OutFileName=OutFileFolder + '\\'+OutPixFileName+sNum[-2:]+'.svg'
    #Save a new file.
    with open(OutFileName, mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as w:
    #Cycle through sample contents
        for sLine in sLines:    
            #Determine whether it is consistent with sTokenString
            if sLine.find(sTokenString)>0:
                print('old->'+sLine)
                #Replaced by a new string
                sNew=sLine.replace(sTokenString,line.replace('\n',''))
                print('New->'+sNew)
                #write in to list
                OutputContext.append(sNew)          
            else:
                OutputContext.append(sLine)
        print(line)
        w.writelines(OutputContext)
    iNum+=1
```